# How do I retrieve an image from folder using the database?

Tags: php

How do I use the file name in the database to retrieve the corresponding file in a folder on the server?

Currently I have a comment section that is working but not sure how to retrieve the image that corresponds with the comment.

MY DATABASE:
comments

STRUCTURE:
cid A_I Primary
uid varchar(128)
date datetime
message text
iamges varchar(50)

HTML:

```
<?php 
echo "<form method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='".setComments($conn)."'><br>

        <input type='hidden' name='uid' value='Anonymous'>
        <input type='hidden' name='date' value='".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."'>

        Select a file:<br><input type='file' name='image' id='image'><br<br><br>
        Comment:<br> <textarea name='message'></textarea><br><br>
        <button type='submit' name='commentSubmit'>Upload</button><br><br><br>

</form>";
getComments($conn); 
?>
```

FUNCTIONS:

```
<?php

function setComments($conn) {
    if (isset ($_POST['commentSubmit'])) {
        $uid = $_POST['uid'];
        $date = $_POST['date'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO comments (uid, date, message, images) values ('$uid','$date','$message','$file_name')";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    }
}       
        if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
            $errors= array();
            $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
            $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
            $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
            $file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
            $tmp = explode('.', $file_name);
            $file_ext =  end($tmp);

            $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png"."gif");

            if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
             $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG, GIF, or PNG file.";
            }

            if($file_size > 2097152) {
             $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
            }

            if(empty($errors)==true) {
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/".$file_name);
                echo "Successfully uploaded file!";

            }else{
                print_r($errors);
    }

}
function getComments($conn) {    

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['uid']."<br>";
        echo $row['date']."<br><br>";
        echo $row['message']."<br><br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the file exists in your database in the `images` column. The same way you `echo` the `date` and the `message` value - you can `echo` the name of the image.

If you want the browser to display it as image (and not only as text) you should use the `<img>` tag:

```
echo "<img src=\"uploads/{$row['images']}\" /><br /><br />";
```

I used the `uploads` folder in the above code (because you uploaded your files into that folder).

> Note that your code is **vulnerable to SQL Injections**! Read more about [bobby tables](http://www.bobby-tables.com) and you can use [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) to learn how to avoid them.

Comment: if I have that set up in CSS for .thumb to change it to thumbnail, how do I change the img src to be and image class?

Comment: and make it clickable?

Comment: Well, that is a completely different question :) regarding the css - you can read here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

Comment: Does this answer your original question?

Comment: it does, just wont let me accept it for 2 more minutes